# Start scanner daemon saned on Fedora Server 31 using systemd

Tags: fedora, systemd

I am trying to start saned using systemd on Fedora Server 31 arm7hl.

My systemd units look like:

saned.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=saned incoming socket
PartOf=saned.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=6566
Accept=yes
MaxConnections=5

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

saned.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Scanner Service
Requires=saned.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saned
User=saned
Group=saned
StandardInput=socket
#StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Environment=SANE_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/sane.d
Environment=SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128 SANE_DEBUG_NET=128

[Install]
Also=saned.socket
```

but when I want to start saned.service, I always get

```
Mar 14 11:00:32 host systemd[1]: saned.service: Got no socket.
Mar 14 11:00:32 host systemd[1]: saned.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Invalid argument
Mar 14 11:00:32 host systemd[1]: saned.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Best regards,
rforberger

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it myself.

I followed the instructions of the man page of saned, where an example of the systemd units is described.

Now my saned unit is still in dead state (systemd) but I can scan remotely anyway....